# Cannot cancel out of unwanted account creation

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

I visited a stack exchange site at which I have no account. I wished to ask a question, but not to associate the activity with my identity across the network. So I *intentionally* *did not* click on 'join this community.'

I was presented with a dialog offering my two choices: create an account linked to my logged-in Google identity, or cancel.

So I clicked on cancel.

And was presented with the same dialog. Rinse, lather, repeat.

Each iteration created an entry in browser history.

Comment: It seems like you were trying to ask on a site that doesn't allow unregistered users to ask questions. I would guess like you were redirected "home > ask > register", and clicking on cancel just sent you back to "ask", redirecting you to register again.

Comment: hm, in which case the error message is confusing ._.

Comment: You can't have two accounts running in the same time in same browser session. Your only option is using other browser, or new browser session/profile then you can create/use new account.

Comment: If it's impossible to do what I tried to do, there should be a dialog box that tells me that.

Answer (score 15):

We released a fix for this today.

Previously, when cancelling profile creation, the user was redirected back to a page that didn't allow anonymous users. That page would then redirect back to the profile creation page, resulting in an infinite loop.

Now when cancelling profile creation, the user will be redirected back to the front-page of the site they were joining. This ensures that users won't land on pages that could redirect them infinitely.

Comment: I can still reproduce this, and so can others: [Ask Question > Create new account? > Cancel > Cancel > Cancel > …](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383949/349538)