# Cannot cancel out of account creation from Winter Bash "Log in or Sign up" link

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, winter-bash

At the top of the [Winter Bash 2022 page](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) there's a link to ["Log in or Sign up"](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/auth/login). I don't have an SO account, so if I click on it I'm prompted to create one, linked to my SE profile. Clicking on "Cancel" from here loops me back to the same page and creates a new browser history event.

This [was fixed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378952/1017231) by changing the redirect URL to be to a page which didn't require authentication, in that case the homepage. In this case the homepage or the Winter Bash page would either work fine.

I am aware of an [outstanding regression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383949/ask-question-create-new-account-cancel-cancel-cancel?noredirect=1&lq=1) of the fixed bug report, but that is for clicking "Ask Question", which I expect would have a different redirect URL from the Winter Bash login button.

Comment: @Catija I take it this one is declined? Or just out of review?